# css menu close all open menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu called css menu.

When I click onto a link I want to close all popups that are open without the
main menu.

I have found some examples, but they are not working for me.

```js
$('#cssmenu a').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).find('ul').is(':visible')) {
    // Close the menus
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <div id='menuspace'></div>
    <li><a href='/0/wall/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>"
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Media</span></a>"
      <ul>
        <li class=''>
          <a href='/0/youtube/' class='ajaxtrigger'> <span>Youtube</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/soundcloud/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Soundcloud</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/mixcloud/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Mixcloud</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/pictures/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Pictures</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>"
      <ul>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/biography/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Biography</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/discography/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Discography</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/agenda/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Agenda</span>    </a>
        </li>
        <li class=''><a href='/0/releases/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Releases</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='/0/contact' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Contact</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put it in a fiddle or any other similar sites and post the link. I am not able to get your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:has()` function to check if the menu item has a submenu. Then by using the `next()` function, you can toggle the submenu.

```
$('#cssmenu li:has(ul) a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cssmenu li ul').hide();
    $(this).next('ul').show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdyw459w/1/)

## Alternativ

This alternativ does the same as the code above. But it will also close the active menu when it's already open.

```
$('#cssmenu li:has(ul) a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(this).hasClass('activeSubmenu') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('activeSubmenu').next('ul').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.activeSubmenu').removeClass('activeSubmenu').next('ul').hide();
        $(this).addClass('activeSubmenu').next('ul').show();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdyw459w/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you! http://jsfiddle.net/Lxf2dLtL/

```
   $('#cssmenu a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#cssmenu ul ul').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
```

Comment: This one did the job for 90 %. It closes all the pops in full screen.. very nice.. only in the mobile view it not closes the top menu..
But i m furter in the code.. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
$('#cssmenu a').on('click', function(){
    $('ul li ul').each(function(){
       $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed / how this fixes the problem? At first glance it looks like you're hiding different elements?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, hope it helps you

```js
$('.has-sub > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("li ul").fadeOut(0);
  $(this).parent().find("ul").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
li ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul><div id='menuspace'></div>
        <li><a href='#' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Media</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/youtube/' class='ajaxtrigger'>   <span>Youtube</span></a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/soundcloud/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Soundcloud</span></a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/mixcloud/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Mixcloud</span></a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/pictures/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Pictures</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/biography/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Biography</span></a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/discography/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Discography</span></a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/agenda/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Agenda</span>    </a></li>
                <li class=''><a href='/0/releases/' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Releases</span></a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#' class='ajaxtrigger'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this have did it for 90%.

```
$('#cssmenu a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#cssmenu ul ul').hide();
$(this).next().show();
```

The only thing that have changed now is that the menu not popup on mouse over and in te mobile version the main top menu that opens the sub menus not close. only the sub menus closes.. is ther a other way then :

```
.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
I have found the solution for my problem.

```
$('#cssmenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cssmenu li ul').css("display", "none");
    $(this).next().show();
    $('#menu-button').parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

To close the main mobile menu button on click i have added this in the script

```
    $('#menu-button').parent().removeClass('open');
```

And added in the css script this

```
    #cssmenu li ul { display: block; }
```

The only thing that was left on page load to block the li ul again.
That fixed it all.

Thanks all